# Blocking users from accessing template files in the theme folder

Tags: wordpress, security, templates

We have been having a problem with hackers trying "break" files by opening by navigating through the directory tree to find them.  For example they would try and navigate to domain.com/wp-content/theme/theme-name/page-custom-page.php and then cause a 500 error when the page would try to load or unload a theme's function.

Our solution was to add the following to the beginning of the template:

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$template_file_path = __FILE__;
if (strpos($current_url, '/' . basename($template_file_path)) !== false) {
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "<h1>403 Forbidden - Access Denied</h1>"; 
exit();
}
```

At first we were banning IP's on Cloudflare, but that resulted in a long list of banned, disposable IP's.  We also tried stopped the directories from being browsed by using the .htaccess.

Now we need to block the method. This problem only exists for custom page templates and the directory tree appears to be as protected as can be, and the code block appears to be working.

My question is "Is there a better way to do this?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common way to block direct access is using the code below.

```
if (defined('WPINC')) { exit; }
```

or

```
defined('WPINC') || exit;
```

They are both common one-liners that are in use within many big plugins. What it does is basically look if the constant WPINC (a built-in WordPress constant) is defined and otherwise [exit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) the code execution.

Some people like to use another constant defined by WordPress called ABSPATH.

Comment: Agreed. Put a line like this at the top of *every php source file you write in a theme or  plugin*. The files where this line should not be there are part of WordPress core. By the time WordPress gets around to using `require` on your source files, those constants are already defined.